# Updating the middle node in a Tree Heirarchy

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have a Tree Hierarchy of nodes that contains a string property. The tree hierarchy contain a Parent child and a child from that child and so on. I have to find and update the string property of one of the middle child from a list and also update the parent and its children. For example,

```
 NodeData[] nodes = new NodeData[]
        {
           new NodeData
           {
              Text = "A",
              Children = new NodeData[]
              {
                 new NodeData {
                     Text = "C",
                     Children = new NodeData[]
                     {
                         new NodeData {Text = "AB" }
                     }

                 },
                 new NodeData { Text = "D" },
              }
           },
           new NodeData
           {
              Text = "B",
              Children = new NodeData[]
              {
                 new NodeData
                 {
                    Text = "E",
                    Children = new NodeData[]
                    {
                       new NodeData { Text = "F" },
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        };
```

In this case I have to find node with text "AB" and then update node "AB" but also update NodeData that has Text "D" , "C" and "A". Im not sure how to go about this I thought about keeping a list and then running thru that list to update the related fields.

Comment: If there was a sibling node on "AB" level, say, "AC", would you also need to update it? Or you need to ascend to the parent level as soon as you find "AB"?

Comment: yes I would need to

Comment: You can always put the parent property into a node so you can move up and down the tree.  On some project I also make a List<Node> so I can access the data sequentially as well as a tree.  The List does not duplicate the Node but accesses the Node by reference so so Any changes to a Node both the tree and list get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at the solution.

Given tree that looks like this:

```
A
    C
        AB
        AC
    D
B
    E
        F
```

and given the need to update all immediate siblings of the needle node and all parent nodes including their siblings, here's my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ns
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nodes = new[]
            {
                new NodeData("A",
                    new NodeData("C",
                        new NodeData("AB"),
                        new NodeData("AC")),
                    new NodeData("D")),
                new NodeData("B",
                    new NodeData("E",
                        new NodeData("F")))
            };
            FindAndUpdateAscendingly(nodes, "AB", x => Console.WriteLine(x.Text));
        }

        private static void FindAndUpdateAscendingly(NodeData[] rootNodes, string dataToFind, Action<NodeData> callback)
        {
            bool FindAndAscend(NodeData[] nodes)
            {
                var needleIsFound = nodes.Any(x => x.Text == dataToFind || FindAndAscend(x.Children));
                if (needleIsFound)
                {
                    foreach (var nodeData in nodes)
                    {
                        callback(nodeData);
                    }
                }

                return needleIsFound;
            }

            FindAndAscend(rootNodes);
        }
    }


    internal class NodeData
    {
        public NodeData(string text, params NodeData[] children)
        {
            Text = text;
            Children = children ?? Array.Empty<NodeData>();
        }

        public string Text { get; }
        public NodeData[] Children { get; }
    }
}
```

The gist of it is in the `FindAndUpdateAscendingly` function. You pass an array of nodes to it, a string you want to find, and a function you want to call on every node you would like to update.

Currently, I'm passing a `Console.WriteLine` as a fake "update" function, just to illustrate the iteration order. Here's the node iteration order as printed:

```
AB
AC
C
D
A
B
```

Basically, it searches for the node with the text you specify, and then bubbles up and calls the `callback` on all parent nodes and their siblings. That's why you don't touch `E` and `F` nodes.

For real data and real usage, instead of passing `Console.WriteLine`, you would pass a function that actually did something to the NodeData. For example, like this:

```
FindAndUpdateAscendingly(nodes, "AB", node =>
{
    node.Text += " - processed";
    Console.WriteLine(node.Text);
});
```